# Как сделать, чтобы меню не сворачивалось при наведении курсора на оверлей?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Имеется бургер-меню на JQuery, при нажатии выезжает основное меню, при ховере на пункт меню появляется второй уровень, далее третий. При клике на оверлей или крестик меню закрывается.
Суть вопроса: как сделать так, чтобы при выведении курсора за границы меню (на оверлей) уровни меню не сворачивались?
Примерная структура:

```css
.main-menu li, a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: black;
}

.main-menu .menu-main-menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu-lvl-2 .lvl-2 {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    background: darkgray;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu-lvl-3 .lvl-3 {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    left: 400px;
    top: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightgray;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu-parent-item:hover > .menu-lvl-2 .lvl-2 {
    display: block;
}

.lvl-2 .menu-child-item:hover > .menu-lvl-3 .lvl-3 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="main-menu">
    <ul class="menu-main-menu">
      <li class="menu-parent-item">
        <a href="#">Пункт меню 1 ▶</a>
        <div class="menu-lvl-2">
          <ul class="lvl-2">
            <li class="menu-child-item">
              <a href="#">Подпункт меню 1 ▶</a>
              <div class="menu-lvl-3">
                <ul class="lvl-3">
                  <li><a href="#">Подподпункт меню 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Подподпункт меню 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Подподпункт меню 3</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Подпункт 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подпункт 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Положение курсора, при котором уровни меню не должны сворачиваться:

[image: Положение курсора, при котором меню не должно сворачиваться(второй уровень)]
[image: Положение курсора, при котором меню не должно сворачиваться (третий уровень)]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Точно не скажу, как это делается на чистом CSS, но делается довольно просто при помощи 10+ строк на JS:

```js
let menuParentItem = document.querySelector('.menu-parent-item');
let lvl2 = document.querySelector('.lvl-2');
let lvl3 = document.querySelector('.lvl-3');



menuParentItem.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
lvl2.style.display = 'block';
})
lvl2.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
lvl3.style.display = 'block';
})
document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
if(e.target.tagName !== 'A') {
lvl2.style.display = 'none';
lvl3.style.display = 'none';
} 

})
```

```css
.main-menu li, a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: black;
}

.main-menu .menu-main-menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu-lvl-2 .lvl-2 {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    background: darkgray;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu-lvl-3 .lvl-3 {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    left: 400px;
    top: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightgray;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="main-menu">
    <ul class="menu-main-menu">
      <li class="menu-parent-item">
        <a href="#">Пункт меню 1 ▶</a>
        <div class="menu-lvl-2">
          <ul class="lvl-2">
            <li class="menu-child-item">
              <a href="#">Подпункт меню 1 ▶</a>
              <div class="menu-lvl-3">
                <ul class="lvl-3">
                  <li><a href="#">Подподпункт меню 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Подподпункт меню 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Подподпункт меню 3</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Подпункт 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подпункт 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```